# I need to write the formulas in the shared link

Tags: errors

Please help me to write the formulas in [this link (from Math.StackExchange)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488964/the-definition-of-nmse-normalized-mean-square-error)?

Comment: Common, you could at least make a screenshot and post the pic here. But i guess nobody will *just give you code*. btw: You can take the mathJax code as a starting point, but be careful, as mathjax is not LaTeX.

Comment: well,I felt the hyperlink wouldn't be so time consuming to open , sorry, but my problem was mostly with the second formula, in the absolute value , but you offered me a really really frsutrating solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press on "edit" below that question and copy the MathJax code. You will have to replace `$$` with  `\[` and `\]`, though. This is valid for this example, but not for every MathJax source you will find.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MSE}{MSE}
\DeclareMathOperator{\NMSE}{NMSE}

\begin{document}
Many papers use the NMSE function without ever explicitly defining it. I have always assumed that 
\[\MSE(x,y)=\frac{1}{N} \sum_i (x_i-y_i)^2\]
and
\[\NMSE(x,y)=\MSE(x,y)/\MSE(x,0) = \frac{\| x-y\|_2^2}{\| x\|_2^2}\]
where $y$ is the approximation to $x$. This gives a simple relation between NMSE and relative $\ell^2$ error. An internet search however only shows strange definitions like 
\[\frac{ \sum_i (x_i-y_i)^2}{N\sum_i (x_i)^2} \quad\text{or} \quad \frac{N \sum_i (x_i-y_i)^2}{\sum_i x_i \sum_i y_i}\]

Is my interpretation not the standard definition?
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd avoid leaving `\frac 1N` in the wild: better teaching `\frac{1}{N}`.

Comment: I changed it, in the wild was a funny expression , but thanks again for that prompt response

Comment: @Farzad64 You are welcome. This was one more of the errors which could appear when re-using MathJax here. So as I said, be careful with that. Regarding your comment below your OP: We do not like external links. On Windows I would not have opened it. Especially from a (maybe) new member of this site. Just for security. And if you are asking for help, you should show as much own effort as possible. Your 'question' was just a "do it for me" post without any information on your background, your done efforts and resulting problems. And by the way the topic is not interesting for others at all.

Comment: ok got you , thank you very much,I think you are right